# How to use exec and du command to find out size of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a script with the **find** command to find all directories with the name "**bin**" within the "**/usr/**" directory. I also want to know the size of each of these catalogues. How would I do this by using the -exec flag and du command?

This is what I've managed to scrape together so far:

```
find /usr/ -name "bin" -exec 

du bin
```

Comment: @WilliamPursell Is there no way of using both?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want.  Do you want the count of files in the directory, or the sum of the size of the files in the directory, or the disk used by all files in (and below?) the directory.

Comment: But probably you are just looking for `find /usr -name bin -exec du {} \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following oneliner outputs the directories and their total file sizes. The `-c` argument produces the grand total of the files inside.

```
$ find /usr -type d -name bin -exec du -shc {} +;

104K    /usr/src/gcc/contrib/reghunt/bin
67M /usr/bin
8.4M    /usr/local/bin
75M total
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you a ton! What does the -type d part do however?

Comment: @hackerNuB restricts the selection to directories, makes sure you don't count a bin file but only the content of bin directories

Comment: @neau I think you should end the command with `+` rather than `\;` so that `find` calls `du` once rather than once per found directory. That would make the calculated total much more useful at least.

Comment: @Aaron, You are correct, thanks for the input! I edited my original comment.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, that worked like a charm! I tried removing the -s argument as well, but I couldn't really figure out what it did?

Comment: `-s` is "summary", it makes `du` show the size of the directory rather than the size of each file it contains. And while I'm at it, `-h` is "human readable" which makes `du` use units when displaying the size.

Comment: @Aaron Brain fart, I knew that. Thanks for the refresher.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /usr -type d -name "bin" -exec du {} \;
```

Comment: in this case `\;` may be changed to `+` to limit the number of process spawned